# How to export a HTML file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to export links that are in my database into a HTML Netscape Bookmark File using [Markio](https://github.com/spajus/markio).

This following Ruby code is from [Markio](https://github.com/spajus/markio). I'm not sure how to get it to work with Rails so I can export links from my database to a file the user can download.

```
builder = Markio::Builder.new
builder.bookmarks << Markio::Bookmark.create({
  :title => "Google",
  :href => "http://google.com"
})
file_contents = builder.build_string
File.open('/path/to/bookmarks.html', 'w') { |f| f.write file_contents }
```

This is what I have so far in my Rails app. I am most likely going about it completely wrong because I only know how to do it with CSV and Excel. Each Link in my Rails database has a `title` and a `url`.

If I navigate to links/export in my browser it should download a file but I get the error "uninitialized constant Markio::Link".

This is my Links controller:

```
def export
    @links = Link.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { send_data @links.to_csv }
    end
end
```

This is my Links model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    builder = Markio::Builder.new
    builder.bookmarks << Markio::Link.create({
      :title => title,
      :href => url
    })
    file_contents = builder.build_string
    File.open('/path/to/bookmarks.html', 'w') { |f| f.write
    file_contents }
end
```

Comment: Try `require "markio"` in your model first?   Actually, looks like `Markio::Link` should be `Markio::Bookmark`

Comment: That's not the problem, i have the Markio gem installed because i have an import option working but i have no idea how to setup it up so users can export.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `Markio::Link` be `Markio::Bookmark`?  I don't see a `Link` object in their API.

Comment: If i do that i get the error undefined local variable or method `title'. So it's not reading the title field in my database from my Link Model.

Comment: Your method is defined as a class method `def self.to_csv`, so therefore there is no `title` method on the class itself.  Define it as an instance method `def to_csv` instead.

Comment: Ok so now i get downloaded file but the contents read out like this #<Link:0x007fd0c45a6878>. It's also downloading a .txt file not an .html

Comment: Where is `Markio::Link` defined?  It doesn't look like it's part of the Markio gem.  This could explain the naïve `to_s` representation of it in the file.

Comment: It's not defined but my rails model is called link so i thought maybe I would do that but thats not right. Im not really sure what i am doing.